# how I can simplify this limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

So I got $f(x) = 1+\sin^2(x)-e^{x^{2}}$

and the limit :

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \cfrac{\ln(1+6x)f(x)}{x^a\cos(f(x))}$$

I have to simplify this limit :(in a form like  $\lim_{x\to o} x^{n-a}$ , or something similar)

- I noticed that $\cos(f(x))$    for x->$0$ = $1$
- I can see => $\ln(1+6x)$  like   $\cfrac{6x\ln(1+6x)} {6x}$ that for $x→0$ is equal to $1$ (and I remain with $6x$)

now I have :

$6\lim_{x\to 0^+} {x^{1-a}f(x)}$

Can you help me simplify $f(x)$ that remains in the limit.

Comment: You can use that for $x\sim 0$ that $\sin^2 x\sim x^2$ and $e^{x^2}\sim 1+x^2$.

Answer (score 3):

By using Taylor expansions, we have that as $x\to 0^+$,
$$f(x) = 1+\sin^2(x)-e^{x^{2}}=1+(x-x^3/6+O(x^5))^2-(1+x^2+x^4/2+O(x^6))\\=
1+x^2-x^4/3-1-x^2-x^4/2+O(x^5)=-5x^4/6+O(x^5).$$
Hence
$$\frac{\ln(1+6x)\cos(f(x)}{x^af(x)}=\frac{(6x+O(x^2))\cos(-5x^4/6+O(x^5))}{x^a(-5x^4/6+O(x^5))}\\
=\frac{(6x+O(x^2))\cdot(1+O(x^8))}{-5x^{4+a}/6+O(x^{5+a})}
\sim-\frac{36}{5x^{3+a}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it.

I took $f(x)$ separately

$f(x) = 1 + \sin^2(x) -e^{x^2}$

$-1(f(x))$ => $f(x) = \sin^2(x) +e^{x^2} -1$

$-x^2(\sin^2(x) +e^{x^2} -1)\over x^2$  = $-x^2({\sin(x)\sin(x)\over xx}+{e^{x^2} -1\over x^2})$ that for x-> $0$ => $-2x^2$

So..

$-12\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^{3-a}$